# How to "observe" .onchange all the elements in an array

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I have an array of elements with class job ie getElementsByClassName("job"), and I'm trying to "listen" on all of the objects in the array ie all the objects of class job. I thought that this would be easier but idk. I feel like there's something I'm not understanding.

But, also on every iteration of .addEventListener("change", saveJobs()); It's executing saveJobs. But it shouldnt only be doing that "onchange."

Many things.

```
for( d = 0; d < jobObjectArray.length; d++)
{
    jobStorageHolder = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("jobStorageArray"));
    if((jobArray[d] === undefined) || (jobArray[d] === null)){
        break;
    } else{
    jobArray[d].addEventListener("change", saveJobs());
    }
}
```

77:85

https://codepen.io/myowncorp/pen/PMGGEj?editors=1010

Here's the full code, with the debugger set to call above the spot of the error. Plz halpxd

The program should addEventListener.onchange to all jobs of name class
The program should save the new job.value to the localstorage
the program should NOT save jobs on each iteration of addeventlistener

Comment: That's because you should pass `saveJobs` (the function) as the argument, not `saveJobs()` (the result of a call).

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple typo you need to do `jobArray[d].addEventListener("change", saveJobs);`
You can also do
`jobArray[d].addEventListener("change", writeYoureFunctionHere );`